# Почему нельзя настроить Nginx + Ruby On Rails без Passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Почему нельзя заставить работать RoR + Nginx без Passenger?
Ведь тот же Php не требует этого.
Но для Django вроде требуется Gunicorn .

У нас всегда админы этим занимаются, и в эти вопросы я не вникал.
Сейчас для общего развития решил почитать. И столкнулся с этими вопросами.

Comment: Вполне можно без Passenger, просто вам нужно поднять на уровне приложения один из rack-серверов, например, можно начать с Unicorn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP требует PHP-FPM. PHP-FPM - процесс, который висит постоянно и выолняет PHP-скрипты, записывая результат в сокет из которого читает Nginx. Ту же самую роль выполняют Passenger, Webrick, Unicorn, Thin. Сам по себе запущенный скрипт ничего не знает о GET-парметрах, POST-параметрах, заголовках и прочем.

Comment: Коротко но ясно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Большинство приложений на PHP, по своей сути, устроены по принципу "рождён чтобы умереть". Т.е. для обработки каждого нового запроса должен быть создан новый инстанс приложения.

Даже использование Fast CGI (PHP-FPM) не снимает это ограничение.
Основная его функция - запускать интерпретатор PHP как демон, благодаря чему его не нужно инициализировать каждый раз.
Приложение же продолжает инициализироваться каждый раз, когда нужно ответить на запрос.

Что происходит в рельсах:
Приложение представляет из себя один большой класс, который, в том числе, реализует [Rack-интерфейс](https://habrahabr.ru/post/131429/). Благодаря такой архитектуре, оно может быть перманентно загружено в память. Задача бэкенд-серверов (таких, как Unicorn или Puma) - держать этот класс в своей памяти, передавать ему параметры запроса и возвращать ответ.

Если коротко (и грубо):

- PHP-FPM сразу создаёт процесс-интерпретатор, который выполняет php-скрипты когда это нужно.
- Unicorn - сразу загружает всё приложение в память и передаёт ему поступившие для обработки запросы.

Теоретически, ничто не мешает написать для приложения на PHP rack-интерфейс и запускать его через Unicorn. Так же, как ничто не мешает использовать CGI, в том числе и Fast, для запуска рельсовых приложений (кстати, вроде были реализации FastCGI для руби). Но нужно понимать, что:

- Рельсы "тяжёлые". Загрузка всего приложения при каждом запросе может быть накладынм;
- Скорее всего, придётся немного дописать каркас приложения, чтобы оно корректно работало.

Comment: Отличный ответ. Спасибо большое.

Comment: "Теоретически, ничто не мешает написать для приложения на PHP rack-интерфейс", но поскольку Rack для Ruby, получится избыточная связка из вебсервера и Rack-хэндлера на Ruby, который передаёт запрос PHP-интерпретатору и получает от него результат. В итоге вместо двух звеньев получится три, так себе затея. А [FastCGI для Ruby есть, внезапно... в Rack](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/handler/fastcgi.rb)!

Comment: @Кнопкатык, `так себе затея` согласен. Так же, как и запуск рельсов через CGI. Я хотел лишь сказать, что такая возможность есть, но не что ею стоит пользоваться (видимо, получилось неочевидно). На счёт юниорна для PHP, могу лишь предполагать что либо есть аналоги, либо это не нужно совсем.

Answer (score 1):

puma c nginx нормально дружат даже с дефолтной конфигурацией. 
добавляем в гемфайл 
gem 'puma', после чего устанавливаем

```
bundle install
```

в nginx пишем самый простой конфиг в файле /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
server {
     listen 80;
     location /{
          proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                }
}
```

Стартуем nginx и рельсы

```
sudo service nginx start
rails s puma
```

И должно работать.